# Calculate Days Under Contract from Table of Contract Start and End Dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe of contracts for specific assets (A, B,...). Each contract has a start date, end date (both inclusive), and a dayrate (contracts cannot overlap). I would like to generate a table that shows how many total days during a specified period (i.e. a date range, in this case a quarter), each asset was under contract. I would then like to calculate total revenues (dayrate * days under contract) for each asset.

I started by generating a list of end dates for the quarterly periods, but am not sure how to continue:

```
pd.date_range(start='9/30/2019',end='12/31/2020',freq='Q').tolist()
```

Here is my sample data:

```
pd.DataFrame([['A', pd.to_datetime('07/30/2019'), pd.to_datetime('08/25/2019'), 5], ['B', pd.to_datetime('08/30/2022'), pd.to_datetime('09/30/2019'), 10], ['A',pd.to_datetime('09/30/2019'),pd.to_datetime('10/31/2019'), 2]], columns=['Asset', 'start', 'end', 'dayrate']).set_index('Asset')

    start   end dayrate
Asset           
A   2019-07-30  2019-08-25  5
B   2022-08-30  2019-09-30  10
A   2019-09-30  2019-10-31  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the problem statement correctly, this should work.

```
# create the dates for each quarter
date_range_quarter_lst = pd.date_range(start='9/30/2019',end='12/31/2020', freq='Q').tolist()

# create tuples of those dates
def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a = next(it, None)

    for b in it:
        yield (a, b)
        a = b
date_range_quarter_zip = [*pairwise(date_range_quarter_lst)]

# extract day by day views between the start and end dates
date_range_days = [pd.date_range(start=_[0], end=_[1], freq='d').tolist() for _ in date_range_quarter_zip]

# function to get the total revenue for the intersection of days
def get_day_count(row, date_range):
    # get all days worked by the contracter between their start and end date
    day_dates = pd.date_range(start=row['start'],end=row['end'], freq='d').tolist()
    # set this with the specified date range and multiply by the day rate
    return len(set(day_dates).intersection(set(date_range))) * row['dayrate']

rev_cols = []
# iterate over each period (quarter) and create a new column
for date_range in date_range_days:
    col_nm = f"total_revs_{date_range[0].strftime('%Y%m%d')}_{date_range[-1].strftime('%Y%m%d')}"
    df[col_nm] = df.apply(lambda row: get_day_count(row, date_range), axis=1)
    rev_cols.append(col_nm)

# groupby
df.groupby(df.index)[rev_cols].sum()
```

Output (pre groupby)

```
        start   end         dayrate total_revs_20190930_20191231    total_revs_20200331_20200630    total_revs_20200930_20201231
Asset                       
A   2019-07-30  2019-08-25  5       0                               0                               0
B   2022-08-30  2019-09-30  10      0                               0                               0
A   2019-09-30  2019-10-31  2       64                              0                               0
```

Output (post groupby)

```
Asset    total_revs_20190930_20191231   total_revs_20200331_20200630    total_revs_20200930_20201231

A       64                              0                                0
B       0                               0                                0
```

Comment: Not quite. Asset A should have zero revenues for periods that start after 2019-10-31 since that’s when it’s last contract ends. I’m looking for an aggregated table that would have rows A, B and cols Q3 2019, Q4 2019, etc. that shows revenues for each asset under all of its contracts.

Comment: If it’s helpful to better understand the question, I’ve similarly asked how to do this in Excel: https://superuser.com/q/1490685/1090414

Comment: Whoops, for the set operation I had `union` instead of `intersection`. Updated.

Comment: Also note that for `Asset B` you have a `start` date > your `end` date.

Comment: Typo in the question. Good catch.

Comment: The last step that this doesn't handle is to group the table by Asset and sum all revenues from all of the individual contracts by Asset (i.e. there should not be two rows for A, only 1 total row for A).

Comment: Added the groupby.

Comment: I think this is actually skipping quarters. So it has from 09/30/2019 to 12/31/2019 as a period and then jumps to 03/31/2020 to 06/30/2020, skipping 12/31/2019 to 03/31/2020.

Comment: Good catch. The tuple creation was not rolling by one element but two. I've updated the code (but not the output)

Comment: Last edit: this implementation double counts the start dates of periods.Q3 2019 (9/30/2019 to 12/31/2019) should only include the end date (not the start date, i.e. it actually starts on 10/01/2019). Note that a contract that has a start date of 09/30/2019 still should start on 09/30/2019 since contract start and end dates are inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates in the dataframe are indeed `datetime` objects, something like this might work. [See the timedelta docs for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)

```py
contracts = {item : 0 for item in df.index.unique()}

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    contracts[index] += row['end'] - row['start']
```